# Convert task data into a flat structure

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data in the below format

```
let input = [
{
    time: "2020-7",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 15
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 13
      },
    ]
  },
{
    time: "2020-8",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 16
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 19
      },
    ]
  },
{
    time: "2020-9",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 12
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 93
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

After config input array, then 'dataConvert' is formatted as follows:

```
dataConvert = [
  ["x","2020-7", "2020-8", "2020-9"],
  ["p1", 15, 16, 12],
  ["p2", 13, 19, 93]
]
```

I tried use `reduce` , I want to find another way of optimizing.

```
let dateConvert = [], valueConvert = [];
data2.forEach(x=>{
   let date = new Date(x.time);
   if (date) {
      let getYear = date.getFullYear();
      let getMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
      let newDate = `${getYear}-${getMonth}-1`;
      return dateConvert = [...dateConvert, newDate];
   }
})
dateConvert.unshift("x");

// get p1 p2 value
let allTasks = data2.flatMap(x => x.tasks);

 valueConvert = Object.values(allTasks.reduce((arr, item) => {
 arr[item.key] = arr[item.key] || [item.key];
 arr[item.key].push(item.value);
 return arr;
}, {}));
dataConvert = [...[dateConvert], ...valueConvert];
```

thank u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a short review;

- The code does not produce exactly your output, the `x` part is different;
  ["x", "2020-7-1", "2020-8-1", "2020-9-1"], I assume the code is right
- That `reduce` is fine, it's the best part of the code really
- The date part seems complicated the check for the valid date could have been done in a filter, the rest in a map
- Consistency is important, you use both the fancy technique `dataConvert = [...[dateConvert], ...valueConvert];` and `dateConvert.unshift("x");` which could have been `dateConvert = ["x", ...dateConvert];`, the only good reason for `unshift` could have been that `dateConvert` is a `const` but it isnt
- I dont like `x` as a variable name, it says nothing to me, I would go for `o` (object)
- Similarly when you reduce `allTasks` you pass `arr` as the cumulator, but it's not an array, it's an object so you could/should use `o` there
- This `[...[dateConvert], ...valueConvert];` is equivalent to `[dateConvert, ...valueConvert];`, you may want to play around more with the spread operator
- `get p1 p2 value` is a very contemporary comment, it is true today because tasks indeed only contain p1 and p2, but the day that tasks get new or changed, that comment will be worthless, consider something like `group all tasks properties`
- I guess a task is an item, but I would rather see `allTasks.reduce((o, task)` than `allTasks.reduce((arr, item)`

If you take all that, I would counter propose this;

```js
function convertData(data){

  let dateConvert = data.filter(o => new Date(o.time)).map(o => {
    const date = new Date(o.time);
    return `${date.getFullYear()}-${ date.getMonth() + 1}-1`;
  });
  dateConvert = ["x", ...dateConvert];

  let allTasks = data.flatMap(x => x.tasks);

  //Group all task properties
   const valueConvert = Object.values(allTasks.reduce((o, task) => {
     o[task.key] = o[task.key] || [task.key];
     o[task.key].push(task.value);
     return o;
   }, {}));

  return [dateConvert, ...valueConvert];
}

const data2 = [
{
    time: "2020-7",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 15
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 13
      },
    ]
  },
{
    time: "2020-8",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 16
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 19
      },
    ]
  },
{
    time: "2020-9",
    tasks: [
      {
        key: "p1",
        value: 12
      },
      {
        key: "p2",
        value: 93
      },
    ]
  }
];

console.log(convertData(data2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
valueConvert = Object.values(allTasks.reduce((arr, item) => {
  arr[item.key] = arr[item.key] || [item.key];
  arr[item.key].push(item.value);
  return arr;
}, {}));
```

This is somewhat opinion-based, but I'd recommend [avoiding reduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) in these sorts of situations, where the accumulator is the same object throughout all iterations. See that link above for a video by some of Chrome's developers going into more detail on why it's not the best idea. In short, while `reduce` is a possible method to solve the problem, it's unnecessarily verbose and can be a bit confusing (especially for readers of your code who may not be sufficiently familiar with `reduce`) compared to a plain loop; it's needlessly complex. Don't feel like you *have* to use array methods everywhere you can (even if using it shows that you know how to use `.reduce`).

You could change it to:

```
const tasksByKey = {};
for (const { key, value } of arr) {
  tasksByKey[key] = tasksByKey[key] || [key];
  tasksByKey[key].push(value);
}
const valueConvert = Object.values(tasksByKey);
```

You use `let` a lot. Best to [always use `const`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6) when possible - this makes code easier to read and reason about, when you know at a glance that a particular variable name will never be reassigned. Consider [using a linter](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const), if you aren't already doing so - it can make code style more consistent and readable, and can reduce bugs.

Similarly, if a variable name doesn't *have* to be reassigned, consider avoiding doing so. Rather than

```
dataConvert = [...[dateConvert], ...valueConvert];
```

you might use

```
const datesAndValues = [dateConvert, ...valueConvert];
```

Remember that `.flatMap` is a pretty new method - if this code is running on a public-facing website, make sure to include [a polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.flatMap). (`Object.values` was only officialized in ES2017, so you'll probably want a polyfill for it too)